# CSS different browser means different output

Tags: css, browser

I have a problem with my css.

When I open my page on IE and Firefox it shows up like this (just like it should)
http://tinypic.com/r/14ni5gk/6

But when I open my page on Safari it shows up like this:
http://tinypic.com/r/2mzdxed/6

(notice the last two boxes not floating next to eachother)

I have the following css code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#container{
    width: 600px;
    background: #fff;
}

#header{
    height: 151px;
    background-image:url('../img/tomaat.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center; 
}

#recent fieldset{
    width : 600px;
}

#stats fieldset{
    width : 600px;
}

#login fieldset{
    width : 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
}

#nieuw fieldset{
    width : 290px;
    float:left; 
    height: 100px;
}

#verwijder fieldset{
    width: 289px;
    height:100px;
}

label {
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
}

#login label{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
}

#nieuw button{
    position:relative;
    top: 5px;
}

#verwijder button{
    position:relative;
    top: 27px;
}

#login button{
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top:5px;
}

#a {
    position : relative;
    top: 43px;
}
#buttonz {
    text-align: center;
}

legend{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

And the following index.php page:

```
<?php
    include_once("db.php"); 
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])){ 
        header("location:main_login.php");
        exit();
    }
    if (!isset($_SESSION['upass'])){ 
        header("location:main_login.php");
        exit();
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Naam='".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND Wachtwoord='".$_SESSION['upass']."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count < 1){
        header("location:main_login.php");
        exit();
    }

?>


<?php
    $date = date("y-m-d");
    $vandaag = mysql_query("SELECT Type, Naam, Reden, Door FROM turfjes WHERE turfjes.Datum = '" . $date . "'");
    $names = mysql_query("SELECT Naam From users");
    $names2 = mysql_query("SELECT Naam From users");
    $names3 = mysql_query("SELECT Naam From users");
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Tomaten turfjes pagina | 258</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery.noConflict();
        </script>
        <script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="js/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
            </div>
            <div id="info">
                <div id="recent">               
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Vandaag</legend>
                        <table border="0">
                            <tr>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Naam</td>
                            <td>Reden</td>
                            <td>Door</td>
                            <?php
                                while($a = mysql_fetch_array($vandaag)){
                            ?>      <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo($a['Type']);?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo($a['Naam']);?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo($a['Reden']);?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo($a['Door']);?></td>
                                    </tr>
                            <?php
                                } 
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div id="stats">                
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Turfjesteller</legend>
                        <table border="0">
                            <tr>
                            <td>Naam</td>
                            <td>Aantal</td>
                            <td>Gedaan</td>
                            <td>Resterend</td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                                while($r = mysql_fetch_array($names)){
                                echo("<tr id=".$r['Naam'].">");
                            ?>
                                    <td><?php echo($r['Naam']);?></td>
                            <?php 
                                        $sql="SELECT * FROM turfjes WHERE Naam='".$r['Naam']."' AND Type='Adtje'";
                                        $result=mysql_query($sql);
                                        $count=mysql_num_rows($result); //count = adtjes
                                        $sql2="SELECT * FROM turfjes WHERE Naam='".$r['Naam']."' AND Type='Turfje'";
                                        $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
                                        $count2=mysql_num_rows($result2); //count2 = turfje     
                            ?>
                                    <td><?php echo($count2);?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo($count);?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo($count2-$count);?></td>
                                    </tr>
                            <?php 
                                }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="actie">
                <div id="nieuw">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Nieuwe turfjes</legend>
                        <label>Naam</label>
                        <select id = "naamnieuw">
                            <option value="" selected></option> 
                            <?php
                                while($r = mysql_fetch_array($names2)){
                                    echo("<option value='".$r['Naam']."'>".$r['Naam']."</option>");
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <label>Reden</label> <input type="text" name="redennieuw" id="redennieuw"/>  <br>
                        <label>Door</label> <input type="text" name="door" id="door" disabled="disabled" value =<?php echo($_SESSION['uid']) ?>> <br>
                        <div id = "buttonz"><button type="button" id="submitnieuw">Turfje uitdelen</button></div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div id="verwijder">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Verwijderen turfjes</legend>
                        <label>Naam</label>                     
                        <select id = "naamverwijder">
                            <option value="" selected></option> 
                            <?php
                                while($r = mysql_fetch_array($names3)){
                                    echo("<option value='".$r['Naam']."'>".$r['Naam']."</option>");
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <label>Door</label> <input type="text" name="door" id="door2" disabled="disabled" value =<?php echo($_SESSION['uid']) ?>> <br>
                        <div id = "buttonz"><button type="button" id="submitdelete">Turfje verwijderen</button></div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <form name="logout" method="post" action="logout.php">
                <div id = "buttonz"><input type="submit" name="logout" value="Log uit"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The boxes are both in the div action
and are called nieuw and verwijder.
Nieuw is the first one, verwijder is the second one.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and maybe even how to solve this problem?

Comment: please provide the html as well in a separate code block

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset?

Comment: It's probably that because of how webkit handles borders and margins, the two boxes cannot fit next to each other, and thus the right box gets pushed to the next line. Can't be sure unless you give us a link to that page. Also, use a reset CSS.

Comment: I have never heard anything about a reset css, can anyone explain me further about that?

Linking to the page is not possible, as a login is required.
I can however post the code, which I will edit in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers have slightly different default settings for thing like padding, margins and font sizes for some elements (for example, the padding on a UL or the size of an H1)

A CSS reset clears these so you can use your own values.

There are many around. I like the [Yahoo CSS Reset 2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/), and for HTML5 there's the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and accurate reply! I will look into it. I have accepted your answer ;)